# Can't compile react-native-svg on react-native-windows

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-windows

I'm working on a react-native-windows UWP application and trying to install react-native-svg but I'm stuck compiling for windows.

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is C:\RN\testapp\windows\packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.0\build\native\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.targets. | RNSVG | C:\RN\testapp\node_modules\react-native-svg\windows\RNSVG\RNSVG.vcxproj | 237 |

Is there something I am missing? I see I'm not the only one experiencing this.

```
react-native-svg: 13.1.0 (also tried 13.2.0)
react-native: 0.69.0
```

I already opened an issue on react-native-svg repo: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1863